# Adding to an array from $row

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

How do I add each result from $row to the $valueIDArray? I then want to use the $valueIDArray to get results from a second database, how do I do that?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM venue
WHERE capacity >= 'partySize'";

//step 2 - executing the query
$result =& $db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($sql)) {
    die($result->getMessage());
}


while($row = $result -> fetchrow()){
    $valueIDArray = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do it this way:

```
$valueIDArray = array()

while($row = $result -> fetchrow()){
    $valueIDArray[] = $row[0];
}
```

Define array before loop, and in loop simple add elements to array using [] after array name

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM venue WHERE capacity >= 'partySize'";

//step 2 - executing the query
$result =& $db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($sql)) {
    die($result->getMessage());
}

$valueIDArray = array();
while($row = $result -> fetchrow()){
    $valueIDArray[] = $row[0];
}
```

You have to add the [] braces. Like this, you always add another entry for the row.

Comment: I see you added declaring array before loop :)